# Error code 1353013. User is not confirmed or is a gray account

Tags: facebook, payment, facebook-credits

We are using the facebook payments subscription api.

We log all errors received by client side FB calls. Recently we have started to see the following errors in our client callbacks:

`Error code: 1353013. 
Error message: "user is not confirmed or is a gray account"`

This does not affect all accounts, we have not been able to reproduce this even with our test users. When looking at /me of the affected users it sais `verified: true`, however we cannot view the profile of the user.

The following FB call is the one we use:

```
FB.ui({
   method: 'pay', 
   action: 'create_subscription', 
   product: 'http://example.com/our/product'
},...);
```

Anyone knows what this error message means? We cannot find any documentation on this error code.

**Update:**

We have found out this relates to facebook business account. I just tried creating one on https://www.facebook.com/business. The error message you get from facebook first is the following:
"You must confirm your account before making purchases on Facebook."

However the business account has a verified cell phone number and can certainly purchase ads through our connected card.

How would one go to report this kind of issues to facebook, Seems like they refer to stackoverflow.com for this kind of reporting?

Comment: Have you created company in your app setting to able to receive payments? I no where see the error code you mentioned in FB documentation.

Comment: We receive payments for normal users. Only users with a "facebook business  account" gets this error

Comment: And that happens to eveyr user with a facebook business account? Are you sure those users were not blocked for spam or forbidden of doing anything in Facebook?

Comment: @IvoPereira yes as far as we can see. We have seen numerous legimate customers get this message. As well when we tried to create an account.

Comment: Are you sure users do not have payments in debt for ads in their business pages?

Comment: For the account we created we did not have any debt and account was verified with a number and had a cc connected